# Why does Eclipse not recognize the build() method from the Notification.Builder class to return a Notification object?

Tags: android, eclipse, deprecated, notificationmanager

This is my code:

---

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) c.getSystemService(ns);

    //Instantiate the notification

    CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(c)
                                .setTicker(tickerText)
                                .setWhen(when)
                                .setContentTitle("Test Notification")
                                .setContentText(arg1.getStringExtra("info"))
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setAutoCancel(true);
    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    mNotificationManager.notify(88, notification);
```

It works find, but using `Notification notification = builder.getNotification();` is deprecated. as I should be doing `Notification notification = builder.build();`.
Problem is Eclipse isn't recognizing it as such, meaning it won't let me compile. The doc is clear that `build()` exists and its the preferred method, but its not working on my end. I would like to use non-deprecated code, so any help will be much appreciated.

**imports**

---

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.Notification.Builder;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
```

Be aware that `import android.app.Notification.Builder;` is saying its not being used.

Comment: Are you targeting API 16? `build()` is new in Jelly Bean.

Comment: Haha, not JellyBean. ICS. Though on a side note if you wouldn't mind answering a quick question unrelated to this one. Should most of the API's from ICS work for JellyBean. I ask because I would like to upgrade to the new OS and try it, but not if my dev phone will not support what I am building my app on.

Comment: Any APIs that are in ICS that aren't in Jelly Bean will only be deprecated, so they will still be safe to use in API 16. But I would run your app on the 4.1 emulator before upgrading your device... just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want develop for version SDK **lower** than 11, you can use this code instead **android.app.Notification.Builder** class for creation notification:

```
private void createNotification(){
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Hello", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);

    Random r = new Random();
    int notificationId = r.nextInt();
    notificationIntent.putExtra("n_id", notificationId);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationId, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Party", "Welcome!", contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);      
}
```

You can cancel this notification in YourActivity like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{ 

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);

    int notificationId = getIntent().getIntExtra("n_id", -1);

    if (notificationId!=-1) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the pipe and equals sign mean `|=`. Is it java specific. But thanks.

Comment: Yes. It's one of the logical operators in Java. The **Bitwise inclusive OR** ( | ) operator performs the bitwise inclusive OR operation on each parallel pair of bits of two operands. In  each pair, the result is 1, if either first or second bit is  1 (or both are 1). Otherwise the result is 0. When used with compound statement like 
**x |= y**  it is to be read as **x = x | y**

Answer (score 1):

This only happens when, You are compiling your app code against the version which does not hold required **method/api** (in your case it is `build()`).

If build is not available in the version you are compiling with, I will suggest you to compile with higher version of Android, You always have **minimum sdk version** in manifest for backward compatibility.

Thanks

Comment: But my sdk version is ICS, which should have this. Though I see what you are saying.